# IE 10 Beta - window.showModalDialog ignores dialogHeight and dialogWidth when opening window which has framset in it

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Note: Issue occurs only with IE 10 Beta release

Scenario:
a.html has showModalDialog to open b.html:
    `window.showModalDialog(b.html, self, 'dialogHeight=800px;dialogWidth=900px');`

b.html has frameset in it :
    `<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="somefile.aspx.vb">
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Frameset//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    Some Title
    </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <frameset rows="40px,*" border="0" frameSpacing="0" frameBorder="0">
    <frame src="myfile.aspx" noresize height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no">
    </frameset>
    </HTML>`

Issue:
When I try to open b.html using window.showModalDialog from a.html, the popup appears in a small window though I gave dialogHeight and dialogWidth. This happens only with IE10. I am using beta version. Please help.

Comment: Also appears to occur on IE 10 Release Preview on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to work around the issue by specifying a [document compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the framesest page:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7" >
```